# customizing css for ultimo theme

Tags: magento2.3.3

Hi am new to ultimo and recently am trying to add my own **custom CSS** in order

Comment: where you have put this css file?

Comment: in my custom module vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\css

Comment: add head tag outside of body tag and inside of page  tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Learning_Module::css/custom-style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Partab, just want to add more details to the answer. The file has to be exactly `app/design/frontend/Infortis/custom/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`
where Infortis - is the theme vendor name, custom - name of the child theme, Magento_Theme - is the folder where the default_head_block.xml has to be stored, otherwise, it won't work.

The content of the .xml has to be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then you can add your own css rules to custom.css file. custome.css has to be stored at `app/design/frontend/Infortis/custom/web/css/custom.css`

Then you would delete the content of pub/static except the .htaccess file, then do the static deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then flush and clean magento cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Cleaning Magento cache is not necessary, but it will help sometimes.